# Severities of all logs on AI Platform are errors

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

On Google AI Platform, all logs printed on stderr are interpreted as ERROR.
Is there any way to print logs as INFO, WARNING, and CRITICAL?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using FastAPI which sends all logs to standard error, leading to the ERROR severity in Cloud Logging. The solution was to add a FastAPI logging config file that instead sends logs to standard out. Then, the Python severity was used as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AI Platform troubleshooting documentation for [training logs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting#training_logs). There is stated that `You can put logging events in your application with standard Python libraries`, such like [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

I haven't tried it but it seems that you can use the logger object class to set the log level desired:

```
Logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
Logs a message with level INFO on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().

Logger.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
Logs a message with level WARNING on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().

Logger.critical(msg, *args, **kwargs)
Logs a message with level CRITICAL on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().
```

Comment: I tried logging module, but the result is the picture above. Though writing `logger.info`, it's interpreted as severity ERROR.

Comment: Take a look at this other [python logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python), it may be helpful, however it seems that the logs from AI Platform are captured into stderr and are hence labeled as "ERROR" type. Also, take a look at the [audit logs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/audit-logs), this kind of logs are slightly different but they are useful depending on the use case.